# How is the data in a MongoDB database stored on disk?

Tags: mongodb, database

I know that `MongoDB` accepts and retrieves records as JSON/BSON objects, but how does it actually store these files on disk? Are they stored as a collection of individual `*.json` files or as one large file? I have a hunch as to the latter, since the `MongoDB` docs state that it works best on systems with `ext4/xfs`, which are better at handling large files. Can anyone confirm?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

A given mongo database is broken up into a series of BSON files on disk, with increasing size up to 2GB.  BSON is its own format, built specifically for MongoDB.

These slides should answer all of your questions:

http://www.slideshare.net/mdirolf/inside-mongodb-the-internals-of-an-opensource-database

Comment: Unfortunately the link is broken

Answer (score 25):

MongoDB stores the data on the disk as BSON in your data path directory, which is usually */data/db*. There should be two files per collection there, *collection.0*, which stores the data (and that integer is then incremented as needs be) and *collection.ns* which stores the namespacing metadata for the collection.

Comment: this answer is better than the chosen one.

Comment: This is exactly the information i have been looking for but i need more details and resources to study it in detail and I'm struggling to find resources to refer would you be able to point me to some, thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

Detailed documentation of the BSON format can be found here: http://bsonspec.org/

Answer (score 3):

Up to mongodb 3.0 
http://blog.mongolab.com/2014/01/how-big-is-your-mongodb/
If you turn on wiredtiger storage engine in MongoDB 3.0 it will use wiredtiger storage model
http://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/core/storage/#storage-wiredtiger

Comment: Not sure how BSON format is transformed or reused by WiredTiger but some more details of wiredtiger file format can be found at: http://source.wiredtiger.com/3.2.1/file_formats.html