# Rails - Where MongoDB (Mongoid) stores db and logs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid

I am new to MongoDB and [Mongoid](https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid) and I am using Debian testing(`jessie/sid`).

When I open `/etc/mongodb.conf` there is no information about where Mongoid stores db and logs.

It just mentions `logpath=/var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log`

Also in `config/mongoid.yml` there is no useful info:

```
development:
  sessions:
    default:
      hosts:
        - localhost:27017
      database: project_development
```

How to locate `project_development` db on disk and logs for that db? Is there a settings somewhere for that?

Comment: this is not related to mongoid, its related to mongodb

Comment: @Muntasim OK added a little edit...

Comment: logpath is where mongodb stores `mongod` logs.  If mongoid has any of its own logging it would *not* go there.

Comment: @AsyaKamsky soooo... where `Mongoid` logs go by default?

Comment: OK I found DB's. They are by default (where there is no `/data/db/` dir) in `/var/lib/mongodb`. But still I haven't found DB logs.

Comment: I don't think mongoid logs anything. what exactly are you trying to find in the logs?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Databases are under:

`/var/lib/mongodb`

MongoDB stores all logs (for each database) in one file by default. It is located under:

`/var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log`

---

More info :

`/etc/mongodb.conf`

- (Using XUbuntu 13.04)

Comment: For me it was /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

Answer (score 4):

usually the log files should be at /var/log/mongodb.log or try `find / -name mongodb.log`.

usually it keeps  data at /data/db.

To know more about where does it store data please visit [How is the data in a MongoDB database stored on disk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4127386/how-is-the-data-in-a-mongodb-database-stored-on-disk)

Comment: So everything it is in just one file? Do MongoDB split logs into separate files?