# mongo DB deleted regularly

Tags: mongodb

I have a serious probem.I dont know exactly what hapened with my mongo database.

every 3 days , whene i try to connect to my website, i found the database empty.

again, i restore it. but after 3 or 4 days, it became empty again .

```html
> show dbs

mydatabase       0.000GB
```

any one have an idea what gone one there ?

any help would be appreciated . Thanks

Comment: is your MongoDB open to the internet without a firewall?

Comment: @Alnitak  No, it is secured and stored in an online server

Comment: Have you checked the logs?

Comment: @VinceBowdren   how to check the logs ?

Comment: @nassim The log file is typically created at /var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log, but it depends on the way you have it installed and configured; take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/17136648/174843 for more info.